# Three.js - Apply heatmap texture to pointcloud

Tags: three.js, 3d, webgl

What I would like to do is apply a heatmap texture to the pointcloud, so that when the pointcloud is rotated, the texture does NOT rotate. For example red needs to always be Z up and blue needs to be Z down.

Is it possible to add the texture to Points object and make it "locked" in place so it does not rotate with the geometry? Or do I need to create another object like cube which has the texture and somehow blend it with the pointcloud?

Is creating shader or putting the color attribute to the vertex the only choice?

All comments and advice greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very rough option, using modified `PointsMaterial` and `Box3`:

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
console.clear();
import * as THREE from 'https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js';

import { OrbitControls } from 'https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { PCDLoader } from 'https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/loaders/PCDLoader.js';

let camera, scene, renderer, clock, pcd;
let box = new THREE.Box3();
let size = new THREE.Vector3();
let uniforms = {
  yMin: {value: 0},
  yMax: {value: 0}
}

init();

function init() {

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
  renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 30, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 40 );
  camera.position.set( 0, 0, 1 );
  scene.add( camera );

  const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
  //controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // use if there is no animation loop
  controls.minDistance = 0.5;
  controls.maxDistance = 10;

  //scene.add( new THREE.AxesHelper( 1 ) );

  const loader = new PCDLoader();
  loader.load( 'https://threejs.org/examples/models/pcd/binary/Zaghetto.pcd', function ( points ) {

    points.geometry.center();
    points.geometry.rotateX( Math.PI );
    
    points.material.onBeforeCompile = shader => {
      shader.uniforms.yMin = uniforms.yMin;
      shader.uniforms.yMax = uniforms.yMax;
      shader.vertexShader = `
        varying vec4 worldPosition;
        ${shader.vertexShader}
      `.replace(
        `#include <worldpos_vertex>`,
        `
          worldPosition = vec4( transformed, 1.0 );
          worldPosition = modelMatrix * worldPosition;
        `
      );
      console.log(shader.vertexShader);
      shader.fragmentShader = `
        uniform float yMin;
        uniform float yMax;
        
        varying vec4 worldPosition;
        
        // https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4dsSzr
        vec3 ansiGradient(float t) {
          return mod(floor(t * vec3(8.0, 4.0, 2.0)), 2.0);
        }
        ${shader.fragmentShader}
      `.replace(
        `vec4 diffuseColor = vec4( diffuse, opacity );`,
        `
          float a = (worldPosition.y - yMin) / (yMax - yMin);
          vec3 col = ansiGradient(a);
          vec4 diffuseColor = vec4( col, opacity );
        `
      );
      console.log(shader.fragmentShader);
    
    }
    pcd = points;
    console.log(pcd);
    scene.add( points );
    
    const helper = new THREE.Box3Helper( box, 0xffff00 );
    scene.add( helper );

  } );
  
  clock = new THREE.Clock();

  window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );

}

function onWindowResize() {

  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

renderer.setAnimationLoop( _ => {
  let t = clock.getElapsedTime();
  if (pcd) {
    pcd.rotation.x = (Math.sin(t) * 0.5 + 0.5) * THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(-60);
    
    box.setFromObject(pcd);
    let yMin = box.min.y;
    let yMax = box.max.y;

    uniforms.yMin.value = yMin;
    uniforms.yMax.value = yMax;
  }

  renderer.render( scene, camera );

});
</script>
```